# Adding a pattern to each field of the following line

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have the following input:

```
MX04A;
DMX04A; DMX04A; LMX04A; LMX04A;
-17.2; -15.3; -14.3; -13.6;
-16.8; -15.4; -16.0; -15.3;
LH36A;
DLH36A; DLH36A;
-11; -117.2;
-11; -17.5;
```

I want to get this output

```
 MX04A:DMX04A; MX04A:DMX04A; MX04A:LMX04A; MX04A:LMX04A;
 -17.2; -15.3; -14.3; -13.6;
 -16.8; -15.4; -16.0; -15.3;

 LH36A:DLH36A; LH36A:DLH36A;
 -11; -117.2;
 -11; -17.5;
```

Comment: (1) Your question title seems to have very little (if anything) to do with your question.  (2) Please *describe* the behavior that you want.  For example, “I have input with semicolon-terminated fields (each line ends with a `;`).  Every time the input contains a line with only one field, I want that line to be replaced by a blank line (unless it’s the first line in the input), and then the value from that field prefixed (separated by a colon) to each field on the next line; e.g., `A;` / `TEAM; TRAIN; GAIN;` becomes `(blank line)` / `A:TEAM; A:TRAIN; A:GAIN;`.”  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  What should happen if one line with only one field is immediately followed by another line with only one field?  What happens if the first line has more than one field?  What happens if the last line has only one field?  What if a line has no fields?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start, that at least works with the example data:

```
sed -r '/[A-Z];/{N;s/([^;]+);\n([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)/\1:\2 \1:\3 \1:\4 \1:\5/;3,$s/^/\n/};s/^/ /' input.txt
```

This is assuming the following:

- Line 1 of each record will always have some uppercase letters
- Line 2 of each record always directly follows line 1
- Line 2 of each record always has exactly 4 fields (this can be generalised, but needs to be exactly 4 for now)
- The remaining lines of each record are always purely numberic, i.e. no letters
- All fields are separated with `space` `semicolon`.
- records in the output should be separated with a blank line, but no extra blank lines at the start or end of output.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer for First Version of This Question (Before the Data Changed)

```
$ awk '/^[^;]*[[:alpha:]];/{a=$1; if (NR!=1)print"";getline; gsub(/(^| )/, " "substr(a,1,length(a)-1)":");print;next} {print " "$0;}' file
 MX04A:DMX04A; MX04A:DMX04A; MX04A:LMX04A; MX04A:LMX04A;
 -17.2; -15.3; -14.3; -13.6;
 -16.8; -15.4; -16.0; -15.3;

 LH36A:DLH36A; LH36A:DLH36A; LH36A:LLH36A; LH36A:LLH36A;
 -11; -117.2; 115.5; 16.8;
 -11; -17.5; 113.2; 15.6;
```

Or:

```
$ awk -F';' '$1 ~ /[[:alpha:]]/ {a=$1; if (NR!=1)print""; getline; gsub(/(^| )/, " " a ":"); print; next} {print " "$0;}' file
 MX04A:DMX04A; MX04A:DMX04A; MX04A:LMX04A; MX04A:LMX04A;
 -17.2; -15.3; -14.3; -13.6;
 -16.8; -15.4; -16.0; -15.3;

 LH36A:DLH36A; LH36A:DLH36A; LH36A:LLH36A; LH36A:LLH36A;
 -11; -117.2; 115.5; 16.8;
 -11; -17.5; 113.2; 15.6;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```sh
sed -e'/-/!N;/;\n/!b' <i >o \
    -e's//:/;y/ /\n/;:n'    \
    -e's/^\(\([^:]*\).*\)\n/\1 \2:/;tn'
```

Or, with `-E`xtended regular expression syntax *(which will work at least w/ AST/BSD/GNU `sed`s)*:

```sh
sed -Ee'/-/!N;/;\n/!b' <i >o \
     -e's//:/;y/ /\n/;:n'    \
     -e's/^(([^:]*).*)\n/\1 \2:/;tn'
```

...which isn't terribly different, and comes to three fewer characters in length.

Or on one line *(for some reason)*...

```sh
sed -Ee'/-/!N;/;\n/!b' -e's//:/;y/ /\n/;:n' -e's/^(([^:]*).*)\n/\1 \2:/;tn' <i >o
```

---

#### OUTPUT

---

```
MX04A:DMX04A; MX04A:DMX04A; MX04A:LMX04A; MX04A:LMX04A;
-17.2; -15.3; -14.3; -13.6;
-16.8; -15.4; -16.0; -15.3;
LH36A:DLH36A; LH36A:DLH36A;
-11; -117.2;
-11; -17.5;
```